# Python, Logistic regression - How to calculate Nagelkerke pseudo r squared

Tags: python, logistic-regression

I am doing logistic regression in sklearn and I would like to calculate (Nagelkerke) pseudo r squared, which makes more sense for logistic regression analysis. I don't see it is available in sklearn metrics. Does anyone have a python code, which calculates this, to share?

Some context:
https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faq-what-are-pseudo-r-squareds/